# Problem concatenating a character vector in a for loop - only returning the final object

Tags: r, for-loop, concatenation

I am trying to loop through a list of data about hospitals in each state and extract the hospital that matches the ranking specified (num argument). I need to return a data frame with two columns, hospitals and states, that gives the hospital in each state with the specified ranking for the specified outcome, so should be 50 rows.

Problem is that I am getting returned a data frame with only one row containing the data from the last state (WY).

I know that my code is working perfectly for what I want until concatenating the character vectors hospitals and states.

```
rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best") {
    data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
    newframe <- as.data.frame(cbind(data[, 2], data[, 7], data[, 11], data[, 17], data[, 23]), stringsAsFactors = F)
    colnames(newframe) <- c("hospital", "state", "heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")
    splitstates <- split(newframe, newframe$state)

    if (sum(outcome == "heart attack" | outcome == "pneumonia" | outcome == "heart failure") == 0) {
        stop("invalid outcome")
    }
    hospitals <- character()
    states <- character()

    for(i in length(splitstates)) {
        orderoutcome <- order(splitstates[[i]][, eval(outcome)], splitstates[[i]][, "hospital"], na.last = TRUE)
        if(num == "best") {
            num2 <- 1
            rank <-orderoutcome[num2]
        } else if(num == "worst") {
            num2 <- length(orderoutcome)
            rank <- orderoutcome[num2]
        } else {
            rank <- orderoutcome[num] 
        }
        result <- splitstates[[i]][rank, "hospital"]
        hospitals <- c(hospitals, result)
        states <- c(states, splitstates[[i]][1, "state"])
    }
    return <- data.frame(hospitals, states)
    print(return)
}
```

Expected: data frame with a row for each state

Actual: data frame with one row corresponding to the last state (WY)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data, maybe using `dput`? That creates a reproducible example and makes it far easier for other users to help you. :) Welcome to contributing to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Consider re-factoring your code to avoid redundancy in data frame construction, growing vectors in a loop, and bookkeeping required of iterated items.

Instead of `for` loop use an *apply* family method, `by`, the object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`. This is similar to `split` + `lapply` (or in your case `split` + `for`) to build final data frame of ranked hospitals across all states.

```
rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best") {
    if !(outcome %in% c("heart attack", "pneumonia", "heart failure")) {
        stop("invalid outcome")
    }

    data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
    newframe <- setNames(data[, c(2,7,11,17,23)],
                         c("hospital", "state", "heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia"))

    # ORDER ENTIRE DATA FRAME BY STATE, OUTCOME, AND HOSPITAL
    newframe <- with(newframe, newframe[order(state, df[[outcome]], hospital),]
    row.names(newframe) <- NULL

    # BUILD LIST OF 50 DFs FOR EACH STATE SUBSET
    df_list <- by(newframe, newframe$state, function(sub) {
        # CONDITIONALLY ASSIGN ROW SLICE
        if(num == "best") {
            df <- head(sub, 1)
        } else if(num == "worst") {
            df <- tail(sub, 1)
        } else {
            df <- sub[num,] 
        }

        return(df[c("hospital", "state")])                
    })

    final_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list))
    row.names(final_df) <- NULL

    return(final_df)
}
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/BDI30571) *(with random, seeded data for 5 states)*